# Multivariate Confidence Distribution Definition

Tags: probability, statistics, definition

For the univariate case, the definition is. A nondecreasing right-continuous function of the one-dimensional $\psi$, depending on the data $Y$, say $C(\psi, Y)$, is the cumulative distribution function for a confidence distribution for $\psi$ provided has a uniform distribution under $P_\theta=P_{\psi,\chi}$, whatever the true value of $\theta=(\psi,\chi)$.

I did a literature search but didn't find a definition for the multivariate case. Is there a natural way to generalize the definition for the multivariate case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in the multivariate case we have the coverage probability for intervals of the form $I_{X}:=(-\infty,X)$:

$$C(\psi,Y) = P\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^{|X|}X_i\leq \psi_i\right)$$